# Do I need a separate Eclipse for android ADT development.?

Tags: android, eclipse

I already have installed an Eclipse with Blackberry plug in for application development for Blackberry phone. Now I want to develop apps for Android with Eclipse. Do I need to download and install another Eclipse for ADT, or can I just install ADT plug in to the Eclipse I already have which has the Blackberry plug in. If I can use the same Eclipse, how I can manage its workspace so not to mix up Blackberry apps with Android apps?

Comment: Should be no problem, you'll need the Android SDK as well as the plugin. Just create a new workspace for your Android apps to keep them separate.

Comment: +1 I think this is a good idea, I am actually using three Eclipse instances (two for my work, one for android fun). You know, sometimes install too many plugins into one Eclipse makes your IDE looks noise.

Answer (score 3):

You can install ADT on your existing eclipse installation without any problem. You can just create another workspace for Android projects to not mix Android and BlackBerry projects ...

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you to install the new eclipse** (so you will have 2 eclipses). I tried to add Android and Blackberry plugin to my Eclipse **Indigo**(and i use different workspace) and it gave me an error, and i cant build any Android/Blackberry project after that.

**Anyway some people said that you can still use 1 eclipse for both plugin but the Blackberry plugin must be installed first.**